# PHPExcel loading message during file generation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

My page has a link that downloads an excel file with PHPExcel. This file is very large and it spends a lot of time. I want to show a loader dialog, or disable the link during the file is generating.

I tried to show a div with `$(document).ready()` but not working. It seems that the download not reload the page.

Comment: "t seems that the download not reload the page." what in earth is that?

Comment: A request can either send a download, or request a page, but not both.... one request, one response, that's the way the http protocol works

Comment: removed unnecessary salutation